# How to create role-based access control or custom claims in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building an Android app with firebase-auth and firebase-ui-auth for authentication and data in Firestore. I want to have some features only available to admin users so I need to implement some sort of role-based access control.  I have not been able to find any examples in the Firebase documentation.  But I have been able to find [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims).  It describes functionality found in the firebase-admin library.

I've just updated my Firebase libraries to 15.0.0, but the firebase-admin is currently only at version 5.9.0 and will not load in Android as I get the following error:

`All firebase libraries must be either above or below 14.0.0`

A few questions:

1. Do I need to create a separate Web Admin project to use the firebase-admin library?  What is the recommended approach?
2. Where are these claims stored?  I'm assuming it's outside of my firebase project, but it would be cool to see this info in the console authentication/user table.
3. Can someone share an Android/Java example of how I would read this new custom "admin" claim from my Android app?  The page seems to only include a JavaScript client example.

Comment: You can implement role-based access control using security rules. Have you check out this page, https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access ?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is pretty clear on this.
You can't use firebase-admin on the client. This runs on your server.

1. You need server side code using firebase-admin to set the custom claims as they are not to be set from the client. You can't let the client define their privileges. This is done from a server.
2. The claims are stored in the Firebase Auth users database for your project and propagated to a corresponding user's ID token. You can't see it from the Console. You can inspect these claims by looking up users via the admin sdk.
3. You can now get it directly from the [`GetTokenResult`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/GetTokenResult). The `getClaim` method returns the map with the claims.